# Adding and scaling polynomials in python using class

Tags: python

I'm making a polynomial class but can't get the add and scale function to work properly.

The scale function should work by multiplying the coefficients of the polynomial by a given x. For example if `y=2x^3+4x^2` and `x=2`, then `y=4x^3+8x^2`

The add function should just add like terms of two polynomials.

I've added comments to the code to hopefully explain how I was trying to get the functions to work

```
class Polynomial:

def __init__(self, coefficients):
    self.coeffs=coefficients

def scale(self, x):
    return Polynomial(self.coeffs*x)

def add(self, other):
    #getting the highest degree to add from
    self.degree=len(self.coeffs)-1
    other.degree=len(other.coeffs)-1

    maxcoeff=max(self.degree,other.degree)+1
    #adding 0's to the end of the shortest one to make adding easiers (pairwise)
    self_temp = self.coeffs + [0]*(maxcoeff-self.degree-1)
    other_temp = other.coeffs + [0]*(maxcoeff-other.degree-1)
    #adding elementwise
    coeffs = [self_temp[i] + other_temp[i] for i in range(len(other_temp))]
    return Polynomial(coeffs)
```

Comment: For a better question, please edit to include what it *is* doing.

Comment: For added interest, you may also want to look into [`numpy.poly1d()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/polynomial.py).

Comment: Your `add` method looks ok (assuming that `.coeffs` is ordered sensibly, so that `.coeffs[0]` contains the constant term), but you should read about [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Answer (score 3):

This is not what you are looking for:

```
def scale(self, x):
    return Polynomial(self.coeffs*x)
```

With that multiplication you are growing/shrinking the list.

Because your `coeffs` is an iterable. This is what you want:

```
def scale(self, x):
    return Polynomial([c * x for c in self.coeffs])
```

And this:

```
self_temp = self.coeffs + [0]*(maxcoeff-self.degree-1)
other_temp = other.coeffs + [0]*(maxcoeff-other.degree-1)
coeffs = [self_temp[i] + other_temp[i] for i in range(len(other_temp))
```

Can possibly better be expressed as:

```
coeffs = [x + y for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(self.coeffs, other.coeffs, fillvalue=0)]
```